# Java Max Heap Size different in jconsole while using G1GC or ParrallelGC

Tags: java, jvm, heap-memory

While working with a Java application using the Oracle Java 11 JVM configured to have a max heap size of 2GB using the -Xmx option, I noticed a difference depending on the garbage collector that I use.

Using the G1GC garbage collector and the jconsole tool, we can check in the VM summary tab of jconsole that the actual max heap size is 2097152 bytes (2048MB) as expected.

[image: G1GC]

But using the ParallelGC garbage collector and the jconsole tool, the max heap size appears to be 1,864,192 bytes (1820MB), which means the `-Xmx` parameter value is not enforced.

[image: ParallelGC]

I have checked with another Java application using the same JVM and I have the same behavior.

I see the same behavior with Oracle Java version 11.0.15 and version 11.0.20.

Any idea of why I'm getting this behavior?

I expect the Java heap size max to be the same and in line with the `-Xmx` parameter with both garbage collectors.